# Dependent Select box in append function

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i have two select box where second one is dependent of first and they are working fine but when i dynamically generate them using append function it doesn't seems to work and no any error is thrown...

```
 <select data-show-subtext="true" class=" selectpicker bs-select form- 
  control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="drawing_id[]" 
   id="drawing">
    <option value=""></option>
      <?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  $image=$row->image;  ?>  
       <option data-subtext="<img width='28%' height='90%'  src='<? 
         =base_url("drawing/fabricator/admin_3/".$row->image);?>'>"  
            value="<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>"  >
             <?php echo $row->drawing_name;?> 
      </option><?php endforeach; ?> </select>
```

here is second

```
    <select data-show-subtext="true" class="  form-control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="profile_series[]" id="profile_series" disabled=''></select>
```

my java script code

```
$('#drawing').on('change',function(){
    var drawing_id=$(this).val();
    if(drawing_id == '')
    {
        $('#profile_series').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    else{
        $('#profile_series').prop('disabled',false);
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url()?>/fabrication/aluminium/quotation_size/get_profile",
            type:"POST",
            data: {'drawing_id': drawing_id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(data){
                $('#profile_series').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error Occured');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Now in normal environment its working like a charm second select value are coming from database which are dependent on selection of first one but now my user can generate both these select box dynamically using append function but here my javascript code not working when user generate it dynamically the depend select box not showing anything .

here is my append function ..

```
    $("#dynamic_field").append(function() {
     return $("<div id='row''+j+'' class='row' style='margin-bottom:15px;'><hr><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm' style='margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;'><button type='button' name='remove' id=''+j+'' class='btn_remove btn btn-danger'> <i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></div><div class='col-sm-2  form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Drawing</label>   <select data-show-subtext='true' class=' selectpicker bs-select form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='drawing_id[]' id='drawing'><option value=''></option> <?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  $image=$row->image;  ?>  <option data-subtext='' value='<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>'  ><?php echo $row->drawing_name;?> </option><?php endforeach; ?>   </select></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Type</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control sm' name='type[]' value='' required/> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Profile Series</label> <select data-show-subtext='true' class='  form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='profile_series[]' id='profile_series' disabled=''></select> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Location</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='location[]'/></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Width</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='width[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Height</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='height[]'/> </div> <div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Quantity</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='1' name='quantity[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Fixed</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_height[]'/><br><input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_width[]'/></div></div>");                                                                      
                             });                                
       $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');   

       });
```

its my controller function

```
    public function get_drawing_live(){
         $this->load->model('fabrication/aluminium/quotation_size_model','quotation_size');

           if(isset($_GET['term'])){
               $result=$this->quotation_size->get_drawing_live($_GET['term']);
               if(count($result) > 0){
                   foreach($result as $pr){
                       $arr_result[] = $pr->drawing_name; }

                   //$arr_result[] = $pr->drawing_name; }
                     echo json_encode($arr_result);
               }
           }
        }
```

please solve my problem instead of down voting...

Comment: after appending the  dynamic_field. trigger on change for drawing id.

Comment: i did not get your point dude

Comment: He means that the new dynamic select that is created by the user doesn't have the event registered to it, since only the first select is affected by the registration code.

Comment: am not expert in javascript can you suggest me some solution

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you've to delegate the event on your select box - because at the time where you define the change event the `drawing` select doesn't even exists ...

a solution would be to change your line

```
$('#drawing').on('change',function(){
```

to

```
$('body').on('change','#drawing', function(){
```

Instead of `$('body')` you might choose the next parent element which does exist, because of performance gains...

You can find an explanation on the official jquery page [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried a solution you provided now it listen function from appended parent select box but when i change the value of appended select box its changing the value of parent dependent select box instead of appended dependent select box

Comment: i dont know i think the problem might be your `#drawing` element has to be unique ... (since you declare it with an `id` attribute)

Comment: as i mentioned earlier am not expert in javascript so please suggest me some solution please

Comment: no offense dude i'm not going to write an entire code for you just because you are to lazy to learn the basics..., this hasn't to do anything with js, to understand the html structure properly you should go and study HTML first, take a look here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp,

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event for each newly created `select` element, to do this a clean way would be to use [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes), but to follow with your code:
You could change this

```
return $("<div id='row''+j+'' class='row' style='margin-bottom:15px;'><hr><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm' style='margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;'><button type='button' name='remove' id=''+j+'' class='btn_remove btn btn-danger'> <i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></div><div class='col-sm-2  form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Drawing</label>   <select data-show-subtext='true' class=' selectpicker bs-select form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='drawing_id[]' id='drawing'><option value=''></option> <?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  $image=$row->image;  ?>  <option data-subtext='' value='<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>'  ><?php echo $row->drawing_name;?> </option><?php endforeach; ?>   </select></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Type</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control sm' name='type[]' value='' required/> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Profile Series</label> <select data-show-subtext='true' class='  form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='profile_series[]' id='profile_series' disabled=''></select> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Location</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='location[]'/></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Width</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='width[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Height</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='height[]'/> </div> <div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Quantity</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='1' name='quantity[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Fixed</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_height[]'/><br><input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_width[]'/></div></div>");
```

To something like this

```
var $html = $("<div id='row''+j+'' class='row' style='margin-bottom:15px;'><hr><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm' style='margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;'><button type='button' name='remove' id=''+j+'' class='btn_remove btn btn-danger'> <i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></div><div class='col-sm-2  form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Drawing</label>   <select data-show-subtext='true' class=' selectpicker bs-select form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='drawing_id[]' id='drawing'><option value=''></option> <?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  $image=$row->image;  ?>  <option data-subtext='' value='<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>'  ><?php echo $row->drawing_name;?> </option><?php endforeach; ?>   </select></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Type</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control sm' name='type[]' value='' required/> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Profile Series</label> <select data-show-subtext='true' class='  form-control' data-live-search='true' data-size='8' name='profile_series[]' id='profile_series' disabled=''></select> </div><div class='col-sm-2 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Location</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='location[]'/></div><div class='col-sm-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Width</label><input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='width[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Height</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='' name='height[]'/> </div> <div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'><label class='control-label'>Quantity</label> <input type='text' placeholder='' class='form-control' value='1' name='quantity[]'/> </div><div class='col-md-1 form-group-sm'> <label class='control-label'>Fixed</label> <input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_height[]'/><br><input type='text' placeholder='Height' class='form-control' value='' name='fixed_width[]'/></div></div>");
$html.find('#drawing').on('change', onDrawingChange);
return $html;
```

Of course you also need to wrap your event handler function code in a function which I named `onDrawingChange`.
Also as a side note since you are using multiple select elements you should not give them an `id` (i.e. `drawing`) and rather use a CSS class.
Finally I didn't test this so feel free to test and come back to me for any clarification.

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried your solution but its not working for me

Comment: Forgot the return statement, have added it retry now, what didn't work check the browser Console for JS errors it may help.